# NLP function in Standford NLP returning dtype error

Tags: stanford-nlp

Beginner in NLP and I am trying to run the below code and it is giving the following error.

doc = nlp("Barack obama in Hawaii")

doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()

Error:

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanfordnlp\models\common\seq2seq_model.py", line 193, in update_state
s.data.copy_(s.data.index_select(0, positions))

RuntimeError: index_select(): Expected dtype int64 for index

Answer (score 0):

That is due to pytorch version. You can use pytorch 1.4.0 version. That will solve this issue/error.

Answer (score -1):

Hello sorry but my English is bad, but I think understand the error in English the words "Barack obama" does not exist, but if you replace "Barack obama" -> "Person" the error does not exist.